# How to reuse Document Library Template (.stp file) in another subsite on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, document-library, template

I saved a `Document Library` as a `Template` in subsite A and an `.stp` file was generated.
Now I want to reuse this template in another subsite B.
How can I import this `.stp` file to use it as a template for a Document Library in subsite B ?
I can use it in the subsite A, it appears in the applications list, but I don't found how to use it in the subsite B.

Answer (score 2):

First download the STP file from Site A. For that

Open Site Settings -> List Templates -> Select the list template file and download it.

Now open Site B.

Open Site Settings -> List Templates -> From Ribbon Upload Document.

Choose the STP file.

Comment: There no List Templates under Settings. I am using SharePoint 2013

Comment: Sure it is, under `/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx`? It is only visible on the root site though

Comment: Enable site feature `Team Collaboration Lists`

Comment: It exists in the root site but only visible from subsites root/FR where it was created and not from root/EN. Is that normal ?

Comment: `Team Collaboration Lists` is already active

Comment: A and B are Subsites under the root Site and not different sites. The `List Template` is avalaible on the root site, accessible from the subsite A where it was created but not visible from the subsite B

Comment: This basic req stumped me at first but the answer is good - although you do likely have to Upload the .STP to the root site. The key is then to go to the subsite and unintuitively "Add An App"... searching for the STP name... and bingo! That last bit is possibly why @M3HD1 still couldn't see it on subsite B. HTH.